# How to get the total correct percentage in excel using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the percentage correct in excel giving the following example. For example, you have 2 errors, and 20 documents. 2/20 is like .05 or %5 were errors. I want how many wasn’t errors which is 95%. How do I get 95% using an equation or formula in excel. I will rate high oh for whoever can answer this!

Comment: Try ```=1-2/20```

Comment: This is basic math. `1 - (errors/documents)` gives you the fractional percentage, and formatting the cell as a percentage in Excel gives you the display format.

Comment: Forget about excel, just review your maths

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do your simple maths this way:

```
(20 - 2) / 20 = 18 / 20 which is then for a %

18 / 20 * 100 = 90%
```

Comment: is there a way that I can do 0 errors in 0 documents =100% in excel? Every time I do 1-(0/0) I get a division error but I need it to calculate 100%

Comment: @dev18 you were told the answer to that here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64867577/4961700 But if you do (20 - 0) instead of (20 - 2) then 20 / 20 * 100 will give 100%, again simple maths.

Comment: @dev18 Why you are dividing 0/0? What is the reason?

Comment: @Harun24HR if 2 errors in 20 calculates as 2 / 20 then you have 0 errors how does that work? Ie 0 / 20 = ? Basic jist of the question.

Comment: Forget about excel, just review your maths.

Comment: @EEM mine is fine - see my answer.

Comment: @SolarMike, apologies wrong place for the comment, It's intended for the Question.

Comment: You must divide the number of errors by the number of documents. You will have an error only if the divisor is zero, meaning no documents were checked. Use an IF statement to avoid making the division if documents = 0. On the other hand, if there were zero errors, zero divided by any number other than zero will return zero.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, 2 is 1/10th of 20 and therefore 10%, not 5%. Percent means "per 100" Therefore, to be formally correct, you should multiply both sides of your equation with 10, making for `(2*10)/(20*10)` = 0.1 = 10%

Since 2/20 = 10%, (20-2)/20 must be 90%. Alternatively, 1-(2/20) also inverts the result.